# How to Subtract firebase timestamp with current time and check if it exceeds 5 minutes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular2-moment

I have a angular app in which i am storing records to firebase with the timestamp using `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Now i want to check if the timestamp added to the database exceeds five minutes.

I tried using moment in my Component but it just dosent work . It is giving false data . I guess the data stored in Firebase is in epoch where as i am in india so how to make moment work in Angular .

I am using Angular 2 Moment.

This is what i tried

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';

      edit(i:number){
        const val = moment.unix(this.comments[0].createdAt);// the value is a epoch time that is the standard that is stored in firebase
        const present = moment().unix();

        console.log(moment.duration(val.diff(present)));
      }
```

The Value of this.comments when using it in date

`let ts = new Date(this.comments[0].createdAt * 1000);` = Wed Aug 05 49474 20:09:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

where as for now its like -- Tue Jul 04 2017 14:56:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Please help why its the comments data not is sink with the time it should be july 3 as it was added on that day on firebase

Comment: what is the value of `this.comments[0].createdAt`?

Comment: Its is a epoch time that is stored in firebase

Comment: in millis (i.e. the javascript type) or seconds?

Comment: Seconds unix timestamp

Answer (score 2):

```
const now = new Date();
const ts = new Date(this.comments[0].createdAt);
const diff = now.getTime() -  ts.getTime();

console.log(diff > 5 * 60 * 1000); // this will give you true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript Date object to do the math, i.e.

```
let now = new Date();
let ts = new Date(this.comments[0].createdAt * 1000);
let diff = now.getTime() - ts.getTime();

console.log(diff > 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: its dosent show the right info the message is stored last day but still the console .log says false where as it is more than  mins should say true right

Comment: When i console log them ts - Wed Aug 05 49474 20:09:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  and now - Tue Jul 04 2017 14:56:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: yes, because when you log a date object it applies toString() to itself, which is a human readable string, that's why you're using .getTime() in the diff so that it transforms the date into millis